# Why do I only have a 3 star award after '100% flawless' drumming?

Tags: xbox-360, rock-band

I was playing *(Sittin' On The) Dock Of The Bay (Take 2)* and got "100% Flawless drumming" (including the achievement for it) and yet only 3 stars. Why would I get only 3 stars for 100% flawless drumming?

I am sure something is not working correctly (see picture). I also recorded a video of this situation. Last time I had a couple 99% with 4 stars. That is when I started noticing this problem. Then I went for more obvious proof for the fact that something is wrong.

[image: Song Summary Screen with 3 Stars and 'Flawless Drumming' Achievement]

As you can see in the next picture I have also completed this song with 100% and 5 Gold stars a long time ago:

[image: Same song, 5 Stars, 100% Flawless drumming]

So why would I get only 3 stars for 100% flawless drumming?

Comment: Hardware malfunction?  If the drum kit is sending extra notes that you aren't playing, that would break up the combo and cause you to not have enough points to get five stars.

Answer (score 14):

You only have a 41 note streak. While I'm not specifically familiar with that song, there's a good chance that there are well over 41 notes to play within the song.

You're awarded points not only for hitting every note, but especially for not breaking your "combo". You can break your combo by missing a note, or, more notably in this case, by hitting a drum when there *isn't* a note there.

If you Full Combo a song, you get almost 4x the points versus if you simply hit every note but overhit to frequently break your combo. Stars are based solely on points, and have nothing to do with the percentage of notes you hit.

Comment: Minor thing, but it seems to be a 71 streak, not 41, unless my eyesight is playing up

Comment: @Robotnik It was previously a 41-note streak, but the asker apparently re-did the song and posted his new result. [You can see it in the revision history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/231386/6). [Previous revision for comparison](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/231386/5).

Comment: @Yuuki - Ah ok, no worries